# Настройка Docker контейнера backend ASP.net 6 Core Web API

Tags: docker, asp.net-web-api

Пытаюсь запустить backend (ASP.net 6 Core Web API) в контейнере Docker, получаю все время warning. Не могу найти причину что не так с моим приложением, и какие ключи хочет Docker в данном warning.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: вы не добавили в `volumes` папку указанную в предепреждении